# Get child and sibling pages to one level [Wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my page setup:

- Page 1

  - Page 1.1
- Page 2

  - Page 2.1

    - Page 2.1.1
  - Page 2.2

etc.

I would like to setup my menu so that when you're on page 1, you see the children of the page; page 2, you see the children of that page.

When you're on 1.1, 2.1, 2.2 etc, you see the siblings of that page. But then the tricky part is when you're on 2.1.1, I want you to see the parent and uncle/aunt(?) pages (2.1, 2.2 etc).

Is there a way to do this with wp_list_pages or wp_query or anything? I appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: Use the example from Codex on the documentation  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/#comment-387

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Some good examples that I missed there, however, still nothing that shows the level above when viewing grandchildren. For example, when on Page 2.1.1, you see it's siblings, not 2.1, 2.2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. A bit manual but maybe someone else has a better solution...

```
<?php
global $post;
//Get page parents
$ids = get_post_ancestors( $post );
//taken from Codex https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/#comment-388
if ( $post->post_parent ) {
    $children = wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
        'echo'     => 0
    ) );
} else {
    $children = wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $post->ID,
        'echo'     => 0
    ) );
}
//if child pages have parent iterate through each and output details
if($ids){
    foreach (array_reverse($ids) as $id){
        $getparent = get_post($id);
        echo $getparent->post_title . '<br />';
    }
}
//Output the wp_list_pages
if ( $children ) : ?>
    <ul>
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```